# Multi Column Replace in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, replace, multiple-columns

I am trying to replace the values of two columns in a row based off of the value of another column in that row.  When I compile the code I do not come up with any errors, but the output values end up being 0 no matter if the condition is met or not.  I currently have the following code.

```
case $column1
    when 'value1'
        replace($column2,$column2,'MASKED') and
        replace($column3,$column3,'MASKED')
    else $column2 and $column3
end
```

Is there a way to do what I am trying to do in SQLite?

BTW it works if I am just replacing one column like so...

```
case $column1
    when 'value1'
        replace($column2,$column2,'MASKED') 
    else $column2
end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show the entire SQL statement.

Comment: This is whole statement.  I am using an ETL tool to replicate tables into another location.  This tool has an expression builder tool for doing some custom transformations on the incoming tables.  The expression builder uses SQLite.  Any other SQL that the tool is adding on its own to the script I am unaware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single expression returns a single value, which can be used for a single column.

You have to use two expressions for the two columns. If your tool does not allow to use two expressions at the same time, you have to run it twice.

Comment: Thanks.  I made an expression for each of the two columns in the tool and that worked.